# Regex to for checking if a string only has characters from a specified set of characters

Tags: regex

I have a list of characters.
'(',')','+','_','-','.', (all numbers)

Does anyone know the regex to find out if "myString" contains just the characters specified on that list of characters?

Examples:

`123()912 = true
123abd = false
empty_string = false
12345 = true`

If all characters from myString is in that specified character list, true, otherwise, false.

Thank you.

Comment: @anubhava: updated the question with examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `^[0-9(),+_.\-]*$` should do it. It matches the start of the string, zero or more characters in the list given above, then the end of the string.

Comment: This works. Test cases are below. Thanks! :)
`IS VALID STRING EMPTY ==> true
IS VALID STRING 1a23456789.()_-+ ==> false
IS VALID STRING .()_-+ ==> true
IS VALID STRING __ss___ ==> false
IS VALID STRING .1....+2+()--_3_ ==> true`

Answer (score 2):

```
^[,().+_\-0-9]*$
```

^ - start of string

[... ] - character class defining the symbols and numbers

- - 0..* occurrences - use "+" instead of "*" to make sure there is at least 1 occurrence

$ - end of string

Comment: When I started my post, there weren't any answers.